# this jquery code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found this jsfiddle **[code](http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/zRX2D/2/)**, and I need it and I want to try that in my php file, but it doesn't work, whereas it's the same code, i just copied and paste and I don't change anything, but it still doesn't work.

**My Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $("#update").click(function() {
            $("#counter").html(function(i, val) {
                return val*1+1 
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.jss"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="update" type="button">Click Me</button>
    <div id="counter">10</div>
<?php

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please show me my fault. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you change jquery.min.jss to jquery.min.js

Comment: add the click function to document ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output">10</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing. What did you do? it works now. What was my fault ?

Comment: changes made in `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.jss"></script>` to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` and other `<script>//your code</script>` should be after google jquery cdn and you have to define `$(document)`

Comment: I was changed that jss to js, like @Sjon said, but doesn't still worked. Ok i will keep find the error. By the way, thanks Gaurang.

Comment: I know now, i don't do this: $(document).ready(function(){}. That makes the code run smoothly, thanks again @Gaurang.

Comment: It makes me sad that a proper explanation doesn't get accepted while a copy-paste answer, of which you learn nothing, does. Ever heard of *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day...* ?

Comment: Read comments i have explained how it works and what mistake he made. @Sjon

Answer (score 3):

You should really be able to debug this yourself. Open your javascript console, and notice it says `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. This means jquery isn't loaded. Now look at the URL you put in your script-src. Why does it end with in `.jss`? You have a typo there.

If you correct that you'll still get the same error. Why? Because you use jquery before including it. So put the included jquery library *before* the custom code.

Now, it still won't work. Why? Because you attach an event before the DOM is loaded; so when your script is processed, the button doesn't exist! So have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and you should know what to add, wrap your javascript inside `$(function() {...})` and you're good to go

Comment: I already change the code become <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>, not jss anymore, but still doesn't work. And i tried to download the script js 1.4.4, and i put it into my code like this <script src="/js/js144.js"></script>, but still also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo in `jquery.min.jss`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.jss"></script>
```

it must be `jquery.min.js`

Or you placed your javascript before the jquery reference.